# My app isn't working and not even showing any error in the emulator

Tags: java, android

These are the errors shown in the LogCat

```
2020-04-29 23:17:57.142 2062-2094/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-04-29 23:18:03.538 1797-1797/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-04-29 23:18:03.538 1797-1797/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2020-04-29 23:18:10.763 1714-1760/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2020-04-29 23:18:21.453 2062-2101/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
```

Comment: Try in another emulator, maybe emulator has problem

Comment: I tried in 3 emulators but still it is not running in any of them

Comment: Check if emulator is downloaded correctly or not

Comment: It is correctly downloaded, should I download it again?

Comment: Attach image from what you have

Comment: I'm getting the same error. have you found the solution?

Comment: @MMG: I am also getting a very similar error. Do you have a solution for that problem? Here you can see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953789/network-connection-check-in-android-always-returns-false-altough-network-is-avai