# Network connection check in Android always returns false altough network is available

Tags: java, android, network-connection

I would like to check in my App (before writing to an online database) if I have a network connection. For this purpose I use the code from this accepted answer on Stackoverflow [check network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279144/how-to-verify-if-user-has-network-access-and-show-a-pop-up-alert-when-there-isn/52279317?noredirect=1#comment123644876_52279317)

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    Log.e("LogTag", "Cecking connection");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I always get the following error

```
2021-11-13 12:13:38.812 17259-17259/com.example.td.bapp E/LogTag: Cecking connection
2021-11-13 12:13:40.837 359-359/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2021-11-13 12:13:40.837 359-359/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-11-13 12:13:47.021 372-372/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
```

2021-11-13 12:13:47.021 372-372/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe

In another Stackoverflow question [Failed to open QEMU pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766789/failed-to-open-qemu-pipe-qemudnetwork-invalid-argument) is was said that the problem is due to the Android Emulator and it was recommended to use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the Android manifest, which I did. But the error still occurs and the method `isNetworkAvailable` always returns false altough I have a Internet connection (I tried this 50 times).

Here is the code of my Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.td.bapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Do you know what the problem might be and how to solve this issue?

**Update**: I also tried another solution that I found here [Android check internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection)

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
        return !ipAddr.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But this also always yields false altough I have Internet connection.

Comment: Are you positive that the internet is available? Emulator is sometimes really fragile, for example connecting to the vpn can require emulator restart to get the internet

Comment: @Jakoss: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I am 100 % sure that a Internet connection is available also for the Emulator. I can verify that by storing the data on an Internet database (Firebase database). Even if the Internet checking methods posted above return false, I try to store the data on Firebase Database and I can see in realtime, that the data is indeed stored there. Further I get a positive feedback from LogTag that the data could be submitted (because the write method to Firebase Database was successfull).

Comment: And in the second method you shown - what's the exception thrown there?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jakoss. I get a similar error message as posted above:
2021-11-14 16:25:33.388 283-283/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2021-11-14 16:25:33.389 283-283/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-11-14 16:25:33.870 278-278/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2021-11-14 16:25:33.870 278-278/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument

Comment: @Jakoss: Any comments on my last comment? I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Not really, it seems like some qemu/emulator issue. You should probably report that directly to google

Comment: @Jakoss: Thanks for your answer and effort. I don't think that google would care about my request. But thanks for your hints.

Comment: It's quite possible to be an emulator issue. Try it on a real device.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Thanks for your comment. I tested the code on another Emulator but the result was the same. Those methods always return false altough I have an Internet connection. I will try to look for another solution for checking the Internet connection.